# What is the function of & combined with > bash?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

What is the purpose of & as in `&>` and `&>>` in bash?

Comment: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both connected to I/O redirection [as explained here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

In the case of `&>`, that redirects standard output (stdout) and standard error output (stderr) to a file. For example, let’s redirect the output of date to a file like this:

```
date &> foo.txt
```

That would create—or overwrite—a file named `foo.txt` with the output of `date`. And the contents of that file would be something like this:

```
Sun Oct  4 22:37:58 EDT 2015
```

But in the case of `&>>` that  that redirects standard output (stdout) and standard error output (stderr) to a file. But the `>>` indicates that the file designated should be appended to and not overwritten if it already exists.

So if I ran this command a few times in a row:

```
date &> foo.txt
```

All `foo.txt` would ever have is the output of the last time that command was run since the single `>` indicates that the file content would be overwritten with each run of the command.

But if I run this command with the `>>` a few times in a row:

```
date &>> foo.txt
```

The `foo.txt` file would have the output of `date` appended to it like this:

```
Sun Oct  4 22:37:58 EDT 2015
Sun Oct  4 22:38:06 EDT 2015
Sun Oct  4 22:38:13 EDT 2015
Sun Oct  4 22:38:15 EDT 2015
Sun Oct  4 22:38:16 EDT 2015
```

Just note that `&>>` doesn’t appear to work in Bash 3.x, but works as expected in Bash 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a command called `cmd`:

```
cmd &>filename
```

The above sends both the command's standard out and its standard error to `filename`, overwriting anything that was previously in that file.  It is equivalent to:

```
cmd >filename 2>&1
```

The `&>>` form is very similar:

```
cmd &>>filename
```

This *appends* cmd's stdout and stderr to whatever was already in file `filename`.  It is equivalent to:

```
cmd >>filename 2>&1
```

You can read more about this in `man bash`.